# Firefox 3.6 bug w/ HTML5 block anchors are duplicated when placed around hgroups

Tags: html

I'm having an issue with Firefox 3.6 and have narrowed it down to block anchors around hgroup tags.  The anchor seems to duplicate with all properties still attached.  Is it invalid in HTML5 to wrap an anchor around hgroups or just a bug in Firefox 3.6?  It works fine in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Firefox block anchors w/ hgroup bug</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
    a {border:1px solid #f00; display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Works fine -->
<a href="#">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
</a>

<!-- Works fine -->
<hgroup>
    <a href="#">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    </a>
</hgroup>


<!-- Creates duplicate <a> tag in firefox 3.6 -->
<a href="#">
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    </hgroup>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related to [bug 311366](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=311366).  Compare [your example](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/wrap-links.html) with [this slightly modified version, served as Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/wrap-links.xhtml).  The work-around I've used is from [Remy's blog](http://remysharp.com/2009/04/14/html5-and-firefox2/) via the [WHATWG blog](http://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-firefox-2).  The good news is it works fine in Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick-fix (though it's far from perfect) is to add a `<div>` between the anchor and the hgroup elements, as described here: http://oli.jp/2009/html5-block-level-links/